# SQL Sever Dates in strange format in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Not sure what's going on here, hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Two queries, pretty much the same except the first only selects a date column whilst the second selects an additional column:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CreationDate
FROM Receipts
WHERE CreationDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1
```

Returns

```
CreationDate
1802-11-01 00:00:00.000
```

Second query

```
SELECT TOP 1 Rct_Id, CreationDate
FROM Receipts
WHERE CreationDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1
```

Returns

```
CreationDate
1994-02-14 00:00:00.000
```

The second one is reasonable and expected, more or less dating back to when the dataset was created. I ran a second set, changing the ORDER BY 1 DESC and got

```
CreationDate
5202-11-01 00:00:00.000

Rct_Id  CreationDate
714350  2015-02-27 00:00:00.000
```

I'm just really confused as to why the date would change like this when Selected on it's own. Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: `Order By 1` is order By ordinal number, first sort by `CreationDate`, second by `Rct_Id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ORDER BY 1` is order by ordinal number, which is first column in SELECT

```
SELECT TOP 1 CreationDate
FROM Receipts
WHERE CreationDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1
```

Means take one record from table receipts ordered by `CreationDate` ascending.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Rct_Id, CreationDate
FROM Receipts
WHERE CreationDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1
```

Means take one record from table receipts ordered by `Rct_id` ascending

To get same result as first query use `ORDER BY 2` or **specify column name explicitly (good practice)**. Same applies to `DESC`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Rct_Id, CreationDate
FROM Receipts
WHERE CreationDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CreationDate   /* Or ORDER BY 2 */
```

Comment: Sheesh, bloomin' obvious. Thanks for spotting that, I have a total Facepalm moment. Time to call it a day methinks. Cheers for your help :)